# Get values from multiple different selected drop down list item using JavaScript without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to be able to select multiple values from two different drop-down lists and use the output values to call a separate function. I am able to get each value independently but would like to be able to have a function that gets both values

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select id ="cars1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

  <select id ="cars2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<script>

//select the value from the dropdown table with id ="cars1"
            var selectCars1 = document.getElementById("cars1");
            selectCars1.onchange = function start(){

                var Cars1Value = selectCars1.options[selectCars1.selectedIndex].value;
                 alert(Cars1Value);

            }

       //select the value from the dropdown table with id ="cars2"

            var selectCars2 = document.getElementById("cars2");
            selectCars2.onchange = function(){
                var Cars2Value = selectCars2.options[selectCars2.selectedIndex].value;
                alert(Cars2Value);

            }

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but one is to store the values outside of the function so that they can be used in other functions.

See inline comments for other modifications to your code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select id ="cars1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

  <select id ="cars2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<script>
  // Set up your variables outside of each function so that you can use them outside of the functions
  var selectCars1 = document.getElementById("cars1");
  var selectCars2 = document.getElementById("cars2");
  var cars1Value = "";
  var cars2Value = "";  
  
  // Don't use .onXys properties. Use .addEventListener
  selectCars1.addEventListener("change", getValues);
  selectCars2.addEventListener("change", getValues);  
  
  function getValues(){
     cars1Value = selectCars1.value; // Just get the value, no need to pass index
     cars2Value = selectCars2.value; // Just get the value, no need to pass index     
     
     doOtherWork();
  }
  
  function doOtherWork(){
    alert(cars1Value + " " + cars2Value);  
  }
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Another way, that avoids setting up the variables in a higher scope, is to pass the values directly to the other function that wants to use them:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select id ="cars1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

  <select id ="cars2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<script>
  // Set up your variables outside of each function so that you can use them outside of the functions
  var selectCars1 = document.getElementById("cars1");
  var selectCars2 = document.getElementById("cars2");
  
  // Don't use .onXys properties. Use .addEventListener
  selectCars1.addEventListener("change", getValues);
  selectCars2.addEventListener("change", getValues);  
  
  function getValues(){
     // Do whatever here, but when done, pass both values to other function:   
     doOtherWork(selectCars1.value, selectCars2.value);
  }
  
  function doOtherWork(val1, val2){
    alert(val1 + " " + val2);  
  }
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```